# flash as3 animated line drawing with lineTo and tweenmax

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to animate a line by drawing using tweenmax and lineTo, but flash seems a little confused about the coordinates of things. The lines are also drawn a little shaky. Here's my code:

```
var childArray:Array = new Array(sC0,sC1,sC2,sC3);
var curChild = 0;

function drawLines(){

    for (var i=0;i<childArray.length;i++){

        if (i == curChild){
            var line:Shape = new Shape();
            line.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF1C30, 1, false, LineScaleMode.VERTICAL, CapsStyle.ROUND, JointStyle.ROUND, 10);
            addChild(line); 
            line.x = sP.x; 
            line.y = sP.y;

            var drawer:Sprite = new Sprite(); 
            addChild(drawer);

            TweenMax.to (drawer,1,{x:childArray[i].x,y:childArray[i].y,onUpdate:drawLine,ease:Expo.easeOut,onComplete:incChild});

            function drawLine():void {
               line.graphics.lineTo(int(drawer.x), int(drawer.y));
            }
        }       
    }
}

function incChild(){
    curChild++;
    drawLines();
}

drawLines();
```

But when I use this, it draws lines FROM the proper point, but it doesn't draw them to the actual X and Y coordinates of sC0, sC1, etc. everything seems offset, and the lines are slightly too long in the Y direction. Anybody have a good way of doing this, or see what might be going wrong in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming that each 's' are movieclips on the stage that you are trying to tween through. If so, are the registration points of the 's' clips in the center of each clip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - I see what I did. Instead of saying "`line.x = sP.x`" and "`line.y=sP.y`" - I should have said:

```
line.graphics.moveTo(sP.x, sP.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the "shaky line" issue, you're converting the "drawer" points from Numbers to integers, so it's basically shifting your line to the nearest pixel. Not changing the type will help "solve" that issue:
`line.graphics.lineTo(drawer.x, drawer.y));`

For the point offset, if the objects in "childArray" are in another container, you may need to use `localToGlobal()` to accurately convert the points.

```
var mc:MovieClip = childArray[i];
var pt:Point = localToGlobal(new Point(mc.x, mc.y));

TweenMax.to (drawer,1,{x:pt.x,y:pt.y,onUpdate:drawLine,ease:Expo.easeOut,onComplete:incChild});
```

This is also assuming `addChild()` in your example is adding to the stage or another container whose position is (0,0). If not, you may need to use `globalToLocal()` or a combination of the two.

Comment: Thanks - yeah - for the lines I'll use integers, but for the objects - everything is added to the stage directly and nothing is within a parent container, so I'm not sure what's up with that.